# HTML5 debugging Video embedding

Tags: html, html5-video

I successfully embedded a video into my code, the video shows up on my browser, however the code following the video is not showing up.

When I delete my video embedded code, the rest of my HTML5 code shows up on the browser. How can I debug this issue?

Here's the video code and just a little bit of code that I have following right after the video:

```
<video width="240" height="320" controls>
<source src="Trooper-movie.mp4" type="video/mp4"
Sorry, your browser doesn&#39t support embedded videos.
</video>
<br>
<a href="https://www.googe.com"> Trooper's Instagram</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't close the `<source>` tag and you should put your fallback text after that tag.

```
<video width="240" height="320" controls>
    <source src="Trooper-movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Sorry, your browser doesn&#39t support embedded videos.
</video>

<a href="https://www.googe.com"> Trooper's Instagram</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your missing your closing tag on the source.

```
<video width="240" height="320" controls>
<source src="Trooper-movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
Sorry, your browser doesn&#39t support embedded videos. 
</video>
<br>
<a href="https://www.googe.com"> Trooper's Instagram</a>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Answer (score 1):

> How can I debug this issue?

Since this is practically a syntax error, some [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)s or [Code Editors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-code_editor) may help you recognize it. For example, I'm using [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) which highlights and indicates something's wrong with the code:

[image: vsc editor visuals]

The "`</video`" (red in my VSCode) in your code is not going to be interpreted at all, while the "`>`" (gray in my VSCode) will act as a closing tag for `source`. That way your "error message" words will be interpreted as [HTML attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp) of the `source` tag.

---

An even better way of debugging anything-web is by using browser's [DevTools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_development_tools). In your case, you would open element inspector to see what the browser actually rendered from your HTML code:

[image: firefox html inspector]

You'll notice that everything "after" the video in your code is actually inside the `video` element. As mentioned before, your "error message" words are being interpreted as HTML attributes of the `source` tag. After fixing the error (closing `source` yourself), you'll notice your browser rendering everything as expected:

[image: firefox html inspector after the fix]

---

- [Opening html inspector in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Open_the_Inspector)
- [Opening html inspector in Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/open)